# Discrete Mathematics Graphs Trees

Tags: graph-theory

> (a) A tree $T = (V, E)$ has exactly one vertex each with degrees $2, 3,\ldots , 7$ and no vertices with degrees $> 7$. How many edges does $T$ have?
>
> (b) Same question with $n$ instead of $7$, where $n\ge 2$.

This was a question and they used the handshaking lemma and $|E| = V-1$.
And I don’t know how they combined to get the result??

Comment: Hi could you clarify your question a little?

Comment: I suspect that when you say *corner*, you mean *vertex*. Also, edges don’t have degrees. I’m going to edit it on that assumption.

Comment: What does "where n ≥ 2nd" mean? I assume that N and n denote the same variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $e$ be the number of edges of $T$. Suppose that $T$ has $\ell$ leaves (vertices of degree $1$). Then the sum of the degrees of the vertices of $T$ is

$$\ell+2+3+4+5+6+7=\ell+27\;,\tag{1}$$

so by the handshaking lemma

$$e=\frac{\ell+27}2\;.\tag{2}$$

On the other hand, $T$ has $\ell+6$ vertices, so $e=\ell+5$. Therefore

$$\ell+5=\frac{\ell+27}2\;,\tag{3}$$

so $2\ell+10=\ell+27$, $\ell=17$, and $e=17+5=22$.

If you replace $7$ by $n$, $(1)$ becomes

$$\ell+2+3+\ldots+n=\ell+\frac{n(n+1)}2-1\;,$$

and $(2)$ becomes

$$e=\frac12\left(\ell+\frac{n(n+1)}2-1\right)\;.$$

$T$ then has $\ell+n-1$ vertices, so it has $\ell+n-2$ edges, and $(3)$ becomes

$$\ell+n-2=\frac12\left(\ell+\frac{n(n+1)}2-1\right)\;.$$

To finish the problem, solve this for $\ell$ in terms of $n$, and then use the fact that $e=\ell+n-2$ to get $e$ in terms of $n$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanition just one question where does T = l +6 and later it is e = l + 5??

Comment: @Jonas: $T$ has $\ell+6$ vertices, so it has $(\ell+6)-1=\ell+5$ edges.

Comment: Last question how does ℓ+2+3+…+n=ℓ+n(n+1)/2−1

Comment: @Jonas: $1+2+\ldots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}2$; this is a standard formula that comes up very often. Here we’re missing the first term, so we have to subtract $1$.

Comment: Thanks so much for you to taking your time to answer my questions!

Comment: @Jonas: You’re very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Use that fact that in a finite undirected graph $G = (V,E)$ we have

$\sum_{v \in V} \text{deg}(v) = 2 |E|$

(The handshaking lemma is a consequence of this identity.)

In both the general and the special case where $n=7$, you know the sum of the degrees.